# Can Dell Equallogic share a LUN that's not dirty for NTFS writes?

Tags: dell-equallogic

If I have a dell equallogic san that has a lun and I want three Windows 2008 servers to be able to write to it.  Will the Dell Equallogic product allow me to write to that lun without being "dirty" or corrupt or do I still need clustering somewhere?  The windows servers are not clustered and there is no clustering software.  The three servers would simply see the lun via (I am guessing) iSCSI.

Comment: MarkM has laid out the main options for you in terms of getting that storage mounted and basically accessible but as far as I know, the storage doesn't have any "magic" to keep the filesystem "clean" with regard to multiple hosts doing writes and locking files independent of each other outside of a managed cluster scenario.  In other words, it's down to OS and protocol whether access by multiple hosts can be done cleanly rather than storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to do one of three things:

1) Cluster

2) Mount the volume over iSCSI on one of the machines, and share it to the other two

3) Share the volume from the SAN as CIFS/NFS/Whatever and mount it on all three servers. I don't know if the Equallogics can do that or if they're straight iSCSI. If they're 100% iSCSI you need to do option 1 or 2.